# Network Switching

Tags: wireless, ethernet, wifi-hardware-switch

Is there a way to switch between Wireless and Wired connections **without** switching either of the connections **off** when **both** are connected?

I am using 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

1. List first default gateways (here is my example):

```bsh
route -n |grep -P ^0.0.0.0 -B2
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.64.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp4s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 enp0s20u9u2
```

2. Figure out which is taking all traffic. It is first listed because of Metric column set lower than 101. So we need to "select" this one for deletion. (use `IP=192.168.64.1`)
3. Delete this first default route:

```bsh
sudo route del default gw $IP
```

4. Enable it again if needed

```bsh
sudo route add default gw $IP
```

## Alternative

### with ifmetrics

```bsh
sudo ifmetric enp4s0 123 # higher on table than 101 will make this interface inactive
sudo ifmetric enp4s0 77 #  lower on metric table will make this interface active
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can**, if is what you want, use 2 connections as one. E.g.:

```
Connection 1: 100Kb/s
Connection 2: 350Kb/s
Resulting connection: 450Kb/s
```

This is achieved using the technique *Bonding*.

How many bonding devices can I have? There is no limit.

It's a bit complicated to configure it properly, so I recommend you read [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding) **completely**, and take away all doubts before starting.
And [in this page](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bonding#Frequently_Asked_Questions) you will see FAQs, advanced options and all the information in one single page.

Comment: It is a bad idea. Just quote important info from that answer and give a reference.

Comment: @Gryu I think it's all important. If you think something is not I would appreciate you adding another answer.

Comment: That answer is not big. Just quote it wholly. I said about *important* info in general. If you consider everything important, then quote everything.